# Simple rewrite in apache not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

This is driving me crazy... I'm trying to set up a simple redirect in apache (to mobile site) but it's not working. the module is enabled, and i'm adding the code to the virtual host main config in /etc/apache2/sites-available.

this is the code, it just doesn't do anything... ( I commented out the condition to see if it helps - it didn't ):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example.org/ [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

UPDATE:

if I change the redirect to this, it works (but of course, i can't use conditions):

```
Redirect / http://m.example.org/
```

why is that? what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You have commented the RewriteCond , delete the # before "RewriteCond"

Generate your own .htaccess from here

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: You right, sorry, try to uncomment and delete the double quotes. Then try to change your user agent to one to fix the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, without parentheses in RewriteCond. I tested this and it works for me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example.org/ [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: nope, doesn't work. I commented the condition, so all requests should get redirected, but doesn't work...

Comment: The problem might be somewhere else. Try without `<IfModule modrewrite.c>` to see if it works then. If the module is not available it should give you an error message.

Comment: I already tested and confirmed that the <IfModule modrewrite.c> block gets executed (the module is enabled)

Comment: How about moving the rewrite condition and rule into a .htaccess file and adding the [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive into your virtual host config. Does it work after that?  


Here is something similar to what you are trying to do: http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-how-to-redirect-users-to-mobile-or-normal-web-site-based-on-device-using-mod_rewrite  

The Apache first reads the virtual host config and then the .htaccess file.